# what is Classification in Object-Oriented Design?

Tags: oop

I read the [Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020189551X).In chapter 4 I read about classification.I dont understand what is exactly classification?
Is about finding object?Is about finding module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is categorization of entities or objects or somethings you can imagine using some "common characteristic".

for example,
banana, apple, book, sun, computer, phone

before categorizing,

object -> banana, apple, book, sun, computer, phone

they can be categorized as..

eatable(common characteristic) -> banana, apple
electronics(common characteristic) -> computer, phone

when we categorize somethings, that behavior it self called as classification.

Answer (score 0):

Classification is identifying objects and then **grouping** them based on of similarities or how related they are.